# Mailkit SMTP - StartTLS & TLS flags

Tags: c#, mailkit

I am trying to connect to iCloud via SmtpClient

The settings I am using are as follows:

Server name: smtp.mail.me.com
SSL Required: Yes
*If you see an error message when using SSL, try using TLS or STARTTLS instead.*
Port: 587
SMTP Authentication Required: Yes - with relevant username and password

If I use SSL I get "Handshake failed due to unexpected packet format"

If I don't use SSL visual studio debugger hangs on connect.

I think the problem is I am not telling the SmtpClient to use tls but I cant find documentation on how to do this.

The code is as follows:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient()) {
    client.Timeout = 1000 * 20;
    //client.Capabilities.
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove ("XOAUTH2");

    client.Connect("SMTP.mail.me.com", 587, false); //dies here
    //client.Connect(servername, port, useSsl);
    //can I set tls or starttls here??
    client.Authenticate(username, password);
    client.Send(FormatOptions.Default, message);
}
```

Am I able to set TLS or StartTLS manually. One thing I did try is the following but it did not seem to work

```
client.Connect(new Uri("smtp://" + servername + ":" + port + "/?starttls=true"));
```

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Why are you passing `false` for the `useSSL` flag if you're saying you require `SSL`?

Comment: @Rob I've tried with true and I get a Handshake failed due to unexpected packet format.  

iCloud suggests this: "If you see an error message when using SSL, try using TLS or STARTTLS instead."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `Connect()` method that you are using only allows enabling/disabling SSL-wrapped connections which is not the same thing as StartTLS.

Due to the confusion, I've implemented a separate `Connect()` method that makes this more obvious what is going on:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient()) {
    // Note: don't set a timeout unless you REALLY know what you are doing.
    //client.Timeout = 1000 * 20;

    client.Connect ("smtp.mail.me.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    client.Authenticate (username, password);
    client.Send (message);
}
```

Try that.

Comment: @jstedfast imap client hangs on connect sometimes. until the windows service is forced to restart. is there a way to time it out so that it restarts on its own

Comment: Depends on where it is hanging. If it is in the socket.Connect() call, then no. If it is in the code that reads the greeting, etc after the socket.Connect(), then yes - set the `client.Timeout` value.

Answer (score 7):

You can set your options to "SecureSocketOptions.Auto"
something like this

```
await client.ConnectAsync(mailService.Host, mailService.Port,   SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
```

MailKit will automatically decide to use SSL or TLS.

Comment: What does it use to decide? The port number?

Comment: Port number you must set in your model. It is just port number from google mail or what ever. So I just call my model and ask for port and host from my DB.... But what is important here is "SecureSocketOptions.Auto"

Comment: @PaulKnopf Yes, MailKit uses the port to decide. It's not the best system in the world, but it works 99% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MailKit Doc](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_MailService_Connect_3.htm)

```
Connect(string host,int port,bool useSsl,CancellationToken cancellationToken = null)
```

The useSsl argument only controls whether or not the client makes an SSL-wrapped connection. In other words, even **if the useSsl parameter is false, SSL/TLS may still be used** if the mail server supports the STARTTLS extension.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me over the SecureSocketOptions.Auto option mentioned previously:

```
    client.Connect(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using the samples from the [FluentEmail documentation](https://lukelowrey.com/dotnet-email-guide-2021/), to use "StartTLS" with FluentEmail and MailKit, I ended up with this in my program.cs:

```
var smtpClientOptions =  new SmtpClientOptions
{
    Server = "myserver.blah.com",
    Port = 587,
    Password = "supersecure",
    UseSsl = true,
    User = "blah@blah.com",
    SocketOptions = SecureSocketOptions.StartTls
};

builder.Services.AddFluentEmail("blah@blah.com")
        .AddMailKitSender(smtpClientOptions);
        
Email.DefaultSender = new MailKitSender(smtpClientOptions);
```

And just send email like this:

```
var email = await Email
            .From("blah@blah.com")
            .To("you@blah.com", "You")
            .Subject("You know exactly what this is")
            .Body("Yep, this is an email example I am sending.")
            .SendAsync();
```